# Memory allocation difference between Singleton vs static final instance

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass instance = null;
    private MyActivity myActivity;
    private Button button;

    public static MyClass getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MyClass(){};

    public void initialize(MyActivity activity){
        myActivity = activity;
    }

    public void releaseMemory(){
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

Here in this approach whenver my application exits then
I can release memory by calling releaseMemory() so that myActivity
instance will not be leaked.

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    private MyActivity myActivity;
    private Button button;


    private MyClass(){};

    public void initialize(MyActivity activity){
        myActivity = activity;
    }

    public void releaseMemory(){
        instance = null; //Can't make it null
        //Can do for individual variables
        myActivity = null;
        button = null;
    }
}
```

In this approach as MyClass instance is final I can't make it null
instead I can make individual variables as null.

So is My understanding correct or am I missing anything respective to memory leaks?

Comment: Java has a garbage collector that takes care of memory management. You don't need to explicitly assign references to `null`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic As these are static instances and will be garbage collected only when the class gets unloaded. In Android if I didn't make activity variable null then it reports memory leak

Comment: "Memory leak" occurs if during runtime the same is allocated again and again without releasing it. In your case just your MyClass class stays instantiated until the end of the JVM execution.

Comment: @MickMnemonic garbage collection is applied on not referenced object. setting instance to null will set it elligible by the gc

Comment: @Heri Even if its only one instance, if its sticks around past the last time you'd want to use it, its a leak.  And in Android leaking an Activity can be a serious problem.

Comment: @Gabe: You are right in respect of Acitvities. I'm talking about the MyClass itself. OP did not specify what memory leak she means. In his case in the worst case only one Activity instance would remain. A further call to initialize would replace the first instance reference, so the first instance would be subject to garbage collection. I wouldn't name this memory leak.

Comment: @heri a leak doesn't need to be unbounded to be a leak. Or to cause problems. And here leaking my class would leak am activity due to the private member.

Answer (score 0):

First question, why do you need to keep a reference on an `Activity` object ?

For most usage you just need a `Context` object. So if you want to avoid leaking your `Activity` take the habit to do the following by replacing :

```
private MyActivity myActivity;

public void initialize(MyActivity activity){
    myAcitivity = activity;
}
```

with:

```
private Context myContext;

public void initialize(Context context){
    myContext = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Since Activity is an implementation of Context, your code should keep working. The method `getApplicationContext()` will always return an Application Context which you can leak all you want.

Now if an Application Context is not enough and you really need an Activity object (if you need to start other Activity without creating a new task for exemple), first ask yourself why you can't do that in your Activity class directly. If you can't, then maybe you have taken bad decision regarding your code architecture.

If you really need to store `Activity` object in other object (singleton or not), please remember that activities have a lifecycle, and you need your `Activity` to notify your `MyClass` that it will be no longer available (if you don't, and you forget to call releaseMemory(), then your `Activity` will leak when it goes to background) :

```
public class MyActivity {

    MyClass myClass; // instance initialize somewhere in your code

    onPause() {
        myClass.setActivity(this);
    }

    onResume() {
        myClass.setActivity(null);
    }
}

public class MyClass {

    @Nullable Activity myActivity; // tha @Nullable annotation helps you remember to do null checks before using this field.

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        myActivity = activity;
    }
}
```

In case your `MyClass` is also a `Fragment`, you can do the job of setting and releasing your `Activity` in the methods `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` (those methods are automaticaly called by Android, so you don't need to try to call them in your `Activity`).

Finally, I would advise against your first code sample, because even if you call your method `releaseMemory()` and ensure you have no reference left in your object `A`, there is nothing you can do to ensure an object `B` doesn't still have a reference to your class `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

final field can't be modified. that's why final modifier exists.

second version of your singleton is better regarding conccurency. but it will be never gc'ed until you close the app.